# Recheck luggage in Toronto when flying from BWI to Heathrow via Toronto on Air Canada?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, short-connections, air-canada, yyz

I have an Air Canada ticket from BWI to Heathrow via Toronto Pearson.  Do I need to recheck my bags and must I go through Customs in Toronto?  If so, will 1.5 hour suffice?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.aircanada.com/us/en/aco/home/fly/at-the-airport/airport-information/toronto-pearson-international-airport/us-int.html

No need to grab & recheck the bags, but you have to fill out your Canadian customs declaration card and go through immigration/customs.  1.5 hours should be fine unless there is a total mess at immigration.

Minimum connection time for this would be 60 minutes. See https://www.aircanada.com/us/en/aco/home/plan/check-in-information/minimum-connection-times.html

Answer (score 0):

You should probably read through [this](https://www.aircanada.com/us/en/aco/home/fly/at-the-airport/airport-information/toronto-pearson-international-airport/us-int.html) web page. It has all the information you need. To specifically answer your questions:

1. No, you will not need to recheck your bag
2. Yes, you need to go through Canadian CBP, but (assuming you have a US passport), that will be no problem
3. I've never been to Toronto Pearson Airport but that seems tight to me.

Comment: Minimum connection time for US->International at YYZ 60 minutes. So unless there is an unusual crowd at immigration/customs, that's fine

Comment: Or Canadian passport, of course.  Many US residents are Canadian citizens.